# jquery plugin timers ajax called

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, timer

i have ajax called that i need to fire's each 3 seconds, looking for plugins of jquery [i found this plugin](http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/)  but i can't make it work. Does anybody could help me. See my code below

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "MapZone.aspx/addingData",
        data: "{indicators: '" + 'probando' + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: loadMarkers
    }).everyTime(1000, 'controlled');

}

function loadMarkers(data) {
  //i do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a plugin for this. You could just use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval) to make the AJAX call every 3000 ms:

```
function initialize() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "MapZone.aspx/addingData",
            data: "{indicators: '" + 'probando' + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: loadMarkers
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if you ever need to stop it, setInterval returns a time ID.  You can pass that ID into clearTimer() to stop it.